# How to create consul ACL that allow access to kv-group only by token?

Tags: acl, consul, consul-kv

I'm trying to understand [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) ACL system and it's looks impossible to create ACL that allow acces to some key only by token with default policy "allow":

```
user@server01:~$ cat /etc/consul/conf.d/acl.json 
{
  "acl_datacenter": "dc-example-com",
  "acl_master_token": "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444",
  "acl_default_policy": "allow",
  "acl_down_policy": "allow"
}
```

I created client rule in ACL Rules:

```
key "group1/" {
  policy = "write"
}
```

I want consul to enable writings in v1/kv/group1/* only via token I've got by my new rule.

It's to hard just to change default_policy to deny, because it is production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, I've found the workaround:

```
Anonymous token:
key "group1/" {
    policy = "deny"
}

acl_group1_allow:
    key "group1/" {
        policy = "write"
    }
```